# Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, babeljs, webpacker

I'm trying to add some react components to work in a Ruby on Rails set up, I had these working in a previous version of the program but had some other issues...  since re-setting everything up in rails 5.1 and webpack template I seem to be having some issues with a babel error.

the error below ..

I'm quite new to working with react so any push in the right direction would be great. I've seen similar issues other people were having with versions of babel and webpack not be compatible but I'm not exactly sure how to change my webpack or babel config in a rails set up or if that necessary for my setup?

````
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/worktime/code/granttnarg/Lets-Practice-Again/app/javascript/packs/dashboard.jsx: Unexpected token (35:13)

  33 |   render(){
  34 |     let autoCompleteList = this.state.autoCompleteResults.map((response, index) => {
> 35 |       return <div key={index} className="row show-page">
     |              ^
  36 |               <div id="search-results" className="container">
  37 |               <a href={"songs/" + response.id}>
  38 |                 <div className="card-product index-card"key={index}>
    at Parser.raise (Users/worktime/code/granttnarg/Lets-Practice-Again/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6930)```

My package.json looks like this :

``` {
  "name": "Lets-Practice-Again",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cloudinary-react": "^1.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}```
````

Comment: What's in your `babel.config.js`? This would be what determines how babel processes jsx. It would need to be similar to the template provided by the rails webpacker react installer (did you use that?) https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/install/examples/react/babel.config.js

Comment: Looks like babel is not interpreting JSX properly. Please post your ```webpack.config.js``` and/or ```.babelrc``` files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)."